# Sitecore Continous Integration with TDS + TFS Cloud --> .target file not found

Tags: tfs, sitecore, integration, tds

I have a solution with two projects: a web project and a Team Developer for Sitecore (TDS) project with Sitecore Items. The local package building with TDS works.

Now I want to have continous integration with the Team Foundation Server (TFS) in the cloud, so I followed this: http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=586

I checked the solution and the needed files into source control and created a build definition. When the automated build is triggered, I get this error message:

```
1>Project "C:\a\src\TDS\TDS.scproj" on node 1 (default targets).
1>C:\a\src\TDS\TDS.scproj(318,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\a\src\TDSFiles\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
1>Done Building Project "C:\a\src\TDS\TDS.scproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

This is where the error apparently occurs in the TDS.scproj:

```
<Import Project="..\TDSFiles\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets" />
```

My Solution is named NeueSitecoreInstanzName. The two projects are named NeueSitecoreInstanzName and TDS. The solution also contains the folders Sitecore and TDSFiles with the necessary files. All these are in source control in the TFS. The HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets file is in the TDSFiles folder on the TFS.

Where does the \a\src\ in the path come from? Why isn't that file found? Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Hedgehog TDS software on your TFS cloud server? For the TDS projects to run, the software (and a license) needs to be installed where the build is compiling.

You don't need a separate license for the build server, you can use the same one from your development machine, but it does need to be installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That tutorial I linked shows how to use the build server in the cloud without having to install the TDS there, by copying the necessary files and puting them to source control.

Comment: I would suggest that you missed something as the .targets file is not in the location that the solution expects.